# Uncompress zlib file in android

Tags: shell, blob, zlib

I would like to uncompress my file imporeted from database BLOB (compressed with zlib)

sql query to save file:

```
sqlite3 database.db "SELECT writefile('myfile', bodyCompressed) FROM messages WHERE _id = 1338"
```

In debian etc. I can use:

```
cat myfile |  zlib-flate -uncompress > myfile.txt
```

How can I reproduce zlib-flate command in android? (shell)

Answer (score 0):

`zlib-flate` compresses and decompresses to and from the raw deflate format. Raw deflate is deflate-compressed data (RFC 1951), with neither a gzip (RFC 1952) nor zlib (RFC 1950) wrapper.

You can use the Java Inflater class, specifying `nowrap` as true.

Comment: sure I have a code posted by someone else but where should I run it? In the shell?

Answer (score 0):

```
printf "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" |cat - myfile |gzip -dc
```

will uncopmpress myfile